# can't connect to db in my sql

Tags: php, mysql

i am using mamp on mac to connect to localhost ,i can connect to server successfully but the problem is i cant connect to db, i don't know in which part of query i making mistake since its just a one line query.i also searched different solutions here on stack overflow but they couldnt helpful

```
$username = 'root';
$password = 'root';
$host     = 'localhost';
$database = 'trendnow';
$link = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password);


if (!$link) {
echo 'can not connect to the server';
}
$db_selected = mysqli_select_db($database,$link);
echo $db_selected;
if (!$db_selected) {


echo 'Can not connect to trend now ';
}
```

Comment: Use `mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password,$database)`. Also, what error/output you get?

Comment: does this query used for connecting the db Or only to the server ?

Comment: Thats the ticket Fepippe @FelippeDuarte

Comment: Use `mysqli_connect_error` and tell us what the real error message is. Your custom error message doesn't help to find the cause of the problem.

Comment: @FelippeDuarte the error i got always is can't connect to db '

Comment: You are not doing any error checking. [Just look at the example in the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php) It shoudl be all you need

Comment: okay, let me check mysql_error then  i will tell you what the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Felippe Duarte is correct. What is the database you are trying to connect to?

```
mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
```

- **Localhost** means connect to the server that the program is running on. Sometimes people will connect to a database located on a server that is not local, so this will sometimes be an IP address.
- **my_db** is the name of the database. So if your database was called WebStore, you may have a table located on the database called, computers. The WebStore would be the name of the database and must reside in that last section, like so: `mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","WebStore");`

Here is a tutorial that may help.
http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_connect.asp

---

**Getting a useful error message**

The problem with the stand alone connection is that if there is an error, it won't tell you what it is. Thankfully there are a few ways to find out what the error is.

```
<?php    
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");

//This will check if we were able to start up a connection using the above line
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

// This is an example query. We will check if it failed, and if so, why it failed
// Perform a query, check for error
if (!mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO Persons (FirstName) VALUES ('Glenn')"))
{
  echo("Error description: " . mysqli_error($con));
}

?>
```

http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_error.asp

Comment: i used this query, but nothing happen , the page remain blank

Comment: Should i use my ip address instead of localhost ??

Comment: @ArslanAliAwan I have answered try that to debug. Also write error_reporting(1); ini_set('display_errors',1); at top of your page

Comment: @ArslanAliAwan, I updated my answer. It should help you retrieve an error message. If the website you are building is on the same machine/server/computer as the database, then you should use localhost. It is a safer way to hide your IP address. If you want to try using your IP address, then by all means go ahead. It should not stop it from working.

Comment: @ArslanAliAwan How are you calling this connection? Did you setup a website somewhere and this is on the .php file you are accessing?

Comment: database files are on my same computer , i am using localhost

Answer (score 1):

Hi  `mysqli_connect` requires 4 arguments. You are mixing `mysql` and `mysqli`. Also always try to debug your connection or query if it not works. MySQLi has functions for that so to check connection use this

```
$link = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password,$database) or print_r(mysqli_connect_error());
```

and to check query use this

```
$result = mysqli_query($link,"your query") or print_r(mysqli_error($link));
```

Comment: That's not entirely correct. You can pass four arguments to the connect function, but you can also do like OP does, with three arguments and select a database separately - but the arguments for that are in the wrong order in OPs code.

Answer (score 0):

add

```
error_reporting(-1);
```

to see the error in 1st line of the code.

Answer (score 0):

You have to leave password empty if you will use root as username